# Can struct be Initialized this way?

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization

Below is my code, I define a struct containing `int` and `string` variables. I remembered that In c/c++,
struct can be initialized like this `A a={0}`, And I do this below, However, When I print out its string member b. program crashed with  terminate called after throwing an instance of
`'std::logic_error' what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid`. But if I changed string b to int b
,It does not crash any more. Does anyone know the reason??

```
struct example
{
    int a;
    string b;
};

int main()
{
    example q={0};
    cout<<q.b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine. I can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/vhMPWG). What compiler are you using?

Comment: check this once (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751567/error-when-initializing-a-struct-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-list ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine, check the execution [here](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3w49gb5j8).
Your, output will be empty as, strings in c++ is by default empty i.e. by default size of strings in c++ is 0. So, no output.